# Delete comments from a C file

Tags: c, file, comments, c99

**Purpose of work:** to learn how to work with files using the functions of the standard C library

**Task:**
There is a file with a C program. It is necessary to delete all comments from it and write the code without comments to a new file.

**Explanations and implementation peculiarities:**

1. The program file may be very large. Therefore, the whole file must NOT be read into an array beforehand.
2. Comments can be single-line or multi-line. A single-line comment can also consist of several lines, if it is moved to the next line using the "backslash" character - "\".
3. There are no nested comments in the C language
4. Comments inside string constants are not taken into account
5. A file does not necessarily represent a correct C program. For example, a comment may break without being closed
6. It is allowed both the appearance of a few new spaces and/or line feeds in place of a deleted comment and the absence of some existing non-significant delimiter characters.
7. It is not allowed to delete data from constant strings marked with quotation marks (double and single).

**Input and output data:**
The source file is always named test.c The output file must be named test.wc

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef int BOOL;

int mygetc (FILE *in) {
        for (;;) {
                int c = getc(in);
                if (c == '\\') {
                        c = getc(in);
                        if (c == '\n')
                                continue;
                        if (c != EOF)
                                ungetc(c, in);
                        c = '\\';
                }
                return c;
        }
}

int skip_line_comment (FILE *in) {
        int c;
        while ((c = mygetc(in)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                continue;
        return c;
}

int skip_block_comment (FILE *in) {
        int c;
        for (;;) {
                while ((c = mygetc(in)) != '*') {
                        if (c == EOF)
                                return c;
                }
                while ((c = mygetc(in)) == '*')
                        continue;
                if (c == EOF)
                        return c;
                if (c == '/')
                        return ' ';
        }
}

void removeComments (FILE *in, FILE *out) {
        int c;
        while ((c = mygetc(in)) != EOF) {
                if (c == '"' || c == '\'') {
                        int separator = c;
                        fputc(c, out);
                        while ((c = mygetc(in)) != separator && c != EOF) {
                                fputc(c, out);
                                if (c == '\\') {
                                        c = mygetc(in);
                                        if (c == EOF) break;
                                        fputc(c, out);
                                }
                        }
                } else if (c == '/') {
                        c = mygetc(in);
                        if (c == '/') c = skip_line_comment(in);
                        else if (c == '*') c = skip_block_comment(in);
                        else fputc('/', out);
                        
                }
                if (c == EOF) break;
                fputc(c, out);
        }
}

int main () {
        const char inName[20]  = "test.c";
        const char outName[20] = "test.wc";
        FILE *in;
        FILE *out;
  
        in  = fopen(inName, "r");
        out = fopen(outName, "w");
       
        removeComments(in, out);

        fclose(in);
        fclose(out);
  
        return 0;
}
```

**.zip with tests:** [Google Disk](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e3AvLPXsH7hmIkZpo6J5vYGwGMaK1UbG/view?usp=drivesdk)

1. Test 1 - correct
2. Test 2 - correct
3. Test 3 - missing "/" in the first line
4. Test 4 - expected "* * *" in one line but got * in different lines
5. Test 5 - correct
6. Test 6 - problems with "", got some extra lines like """"""""\"""\" which had to be removed
7. Test 7 - correct
8. Test 8 - stripped out the extra lines
9. Test 9, 10 - problem with combination / and \
10. Test 11 - correct
11. Test 12 - correct
12. Test 13 - correct

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Frankie_C the program doesn’t work correctly but algorithms looks fine for me

Comment: `"doesn't work correctly"` isn't a useful problem description.  You need to give specific input/output examples.

Comment: *"A file does not necessarily represent a correct C program. For example, a comment may break without being closed"*  -- Yikes!  So how will we determine when a comment ends/closes?  This is crucial -- without knowing you could potentially delete an entire file -- ie: The file begins with an unclosed comment.  EDIT:  also, there is no access to your Google Disk for us (or me anyway).  I guess you did not give it public permissions?

Comment: @gregspears I think the idea is that .c is just an extra condition, in fact all tests can be done in .txt as well

Comment: Function `skip_line_comment()` does not take into account condition 2 – a "single line" comment may be extended to several lines.

Comment: OK, so, what jumps out at me is that it appears your code assumes that a linefeed `('\n')` is a two character set beginning with a single character slash `('\')`.  I know it looks like that in print, but it isn't so.  I say this because your code says `(c == '\\')` ...then proceeds to check for a linefeed -- as if a slash is a precondition.  (see especially `mygetc()` ).  A linefeed is actually a single character.  You check for it directly, with no preconditions needed.  Of course, I may have misunderstood the intent of `mygetc()` -- I'm left to guess at the logic since there are no comments.

Comment: I've compiled and run your code.  It works quite well really, in spite of certain areas not being quite clear on logic to me.  If you can explain it all to your prof,  I predict a passing grade...  better than a C.

Comment: Future recommendation: start building the habit of commenting your code, the logic...what the intent of the logic is.  It will help others to troubleshoot your code when you come to Stackoverflow.  Also, it will help you when you need to come back to your code in a week, month or year.   Writing C isn't like riding a bike:  you will forget stuff to the point that you may wonder, "Wow!  Did I actually *write this code*?"

Comment: @gregspears the test for a backslash before a newline is there because it is `C`: you can continue any line ending it with a single backslash, so the sequence `\\\n` is special. I believe it is item 2 on description, but could be more elaborated there

Comment: The test set is not marked public...  What about the question? The generic _why it does not work?_ You could post the failing tests here. It will help you and others...

Comment: @arfneto my bad, made zip public

Comment: Strings and character constants have different rules.  `""` is a valid string; `''` is not a valid character constant.  The comment start symbols can have an arbitrary number of backslash-newline character pairs between then (so a `/*` comment could have a dozen backslash-newline character pairs inserted in the middle).  Similarly with the `*/` comment end marker.  Fortunately, you don't have to deal with C++ raw strings — they are obnoxious.  Presumably, you don't have to deal with C23 punctuated numbers like `0xFFFF'FFFF'FFFF'FFFF` (they're already in C++).  They complicate the scanning.

Comment: You have to note that ```\\``` followed by a newline continues the line; the first backslash does not "consume" or "neutralize" the second. This is defined in the C standard in [§5.1.1.2 Translation phases](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2). Backslash-newline splicing is phase 2; comments are replaced by spaces in phase 3. You can ignore trigraphs — they are not part of C23 any more. The trigraph sequence `??/` maps to backslash and would seriously complicate things. If your code does contain trigraphs, then get rid of them with a completely separate (and much simpler) program.

Comment: To anyone looking at the test data on a Unix-like machine — the files have DOS-style CRLF line endings.  That may well confuse comment-stripping programs because backslashes at eh end of a line are followed by CR, not LF aka NL.

Comment: Another weirdness — a number of the input files do not end with a CRLF (3, 4, 7-13), and a number of the expected output files do not end with a CRLF (1-5, 8-10, 13).  Expected outputs 11 and 12 are empty. Some of the inputs are revoltingly malformed as C code (you cannot start a valid C file with `/"`, for example – see test 10) and definitely not acceptable to a C compiler.  (§5.1.1.2 phase 2 says: _A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place._. Expect problems!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler some outputs have to be empty, that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to completely rewrite the program. Now there is a separate algorithm for each case. It passes all 13 tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 2048
#define CODE                        0
#define STAR_IN_MULTI_COMMENT       1
#define SLASH_IN_LINE_COMMENT       2
#define BEGIN_COMMENT               3
#define STRING                      4
#define MULTI_COMMENT               5
#define LINE_COMMENT                6
#define SLASH_IN_STRING             7
#define LITERAL                     8
#define SLASH_IN_LITERAL            9

void processFile(FILE *filei, FILE *fileo);

int main() {
    char filenamei[] = "test.c";
    char filenameo[] = "test.wc";

    FILE *filei, *fileo;

    if ((filei = fopen(filenamei, "r")) == NULL
    || (fileo = fopen(filenameo, "w")) == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    processFile(filei, fileo);

    fclose(filei);
    fclose(fileo);

    return 0;
}

void processFile(FILE *filei, FILE *fileo) {
    int i, size, pOutStr, state;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE], result[BUFSIZE];

    state = CODE;
    do {
        pOutStr = 0;
        size = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSIZE, filei);

        for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            switch (state) {
                case CODE:
                    if (buffer[i] == '\"') {
                        state = STRING;
                        result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '/') {
                        state = BEGIN_COMMENT;
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '\'') {
                        state = LITERAL;
                        result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    } else {
                        result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    }
                    break;

                case STAR_IN_MULTI_COMMENT:
                    if (buffer[i] == '/') {
                        state = CODE;
                    } else if (buffer[i] != '*') {
                        state = MULTI_COMMENT;
                    }
                    break;

                case SLASH_IN_LINE_COMMENT:
                    state = LINE_COMMENT;
                    break;

                case BEGIN_COMMENT:
                    if (buffer[i] == '*') {
                        state = MULTI_COMMENT;
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '/') {
                        state = LINE_COMMENT;
                    } else {
                        result[pOutStr++] = '/';
                        --i;
                        state = CODE;
                    }
                    break;

                case STRING:
                    if (buffer[i] == '"') {
                        state = CODE;
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '\\') {
                        state = SLASH_IN_STRING;
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
                        state = CODE;
                    }
                    result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    break;

                case LITERAL:
                    if (buffer[i] == '\'') {
                        state = CODE;
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '\\') {
                        state = SLASH_IN_LITERAL;
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
                        state = CODE;
                    }
                    result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    break;

                case MULTI_COMMENT:
                    if (buffer[i] == '*') {
                        state = STAR_IN_MULTI_COMMENT;
                    }
                    break;

                case LINE_COMMENT:
                    if (buffer[i] == '\\') {
                        state = SLASH_IN_LINE_COMMENT;
                    } else if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
                        state = CODE;
                        result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    }
                    break;

                case SLASH_IN_STRING:
                    state = STRING;
                    result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    break;

                case SLASH_IN_LITERAL:
                    state = (buffer[i] != '\n') ? LITERAL : CODE;
                    result[pOutStr++] = buffer[i];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (pOutStr) {
            fwrite(result, 1, pOutStr, fileo);
        }

    } while(!feof(filei));
}
```

Comment: Good idea to rewrite from scratch, and a state machine also makes a lot of sense.  I can find edge cases which, it seems, the tests do not find.  Most notably, the three lines **```/\```** — **```\```** — **```/ comment```** form a "single-line" comment (C++-style double-slash comment).  Similarly with other two-character comment delimiters.  The backslash-newline sequence makes life complicated.  I think we can both safely ignore `#include <double"quote.h>` which, although valid (and does not contain part of a string), would be insane — not that the test cases were sane either.

Comment: I was a bit puzzled by the `SLASH_IN_STRING` and `SLASH_IN_LITERAL` states, but the 'slash' referred to is a backslash.  I would have either used `BACKSLASH_IN_…` or `BS_IN_…`, and annotated the abbreviated form.  That's a very minor stylistic critique.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues in this question:

1. it is unclear whether the output program can differ from the source program in subtle ways such as

   - line endings (LF or CR/LF pairs)
   - non significant initial and/or trailing spaces
   - empty lines
   - suppressed escaped newline sequences (`\` followed by and end of line sequence)
2. the test files are encoded using the DOS end of line sequences (CR/LF) and the expected output files use an inconsistent combination of unix line endings (LF) and DOS end of line sequences.  The zip file also contains macOS attribute files (in the **__MACOSX/** directory), indicating that it was produced on a Mac, which uses unix line endings and does not translate line endings for files open in text mode (`"r"` and `"w"`).  It is likely the expected output files were produced on a mac or on a unix system from DOS source files, where the DOS end of line sequences were copies unchanged from the source files but the `'\n'` output in replacement of multiline comments were not translated to CR/LF sequences by the Standard library as they would have been on a legacy system.
3. the test files contain many inconsistencies such as missing spaces and newlines, even missing final newlines!  The problem statement should be more precise and specify that single line comments must be replaced with a single newline and multiline comments with a single space.  Yet replacing multiline comments with a single space is not always appropriate: in `#define a/**/(b)`, this would cause `a(1)` to be defined as expanding to `(b)(1)` instead of nothing.  A multiline comment should only expand to a space if its absence would cause the next character to be part of the previous token, which is non trivial to implement.

- another problem in the test files is the presence of embedded unescaped newlines inside string literals (eg: **test(5).c** line 8). The **expected test(5).wc** file seems to expect the string to end on the newline.  The source file is invalid, but the behavior on such syntax errors should be specified if any *expected* output is to be checked.

It seems difficult to write a program that will produce the expected output precisely.

Your program is quite straight forward and seems correct, except for a few limitations and errors:

- if compiled on a unix system, it does not recognise CR/LF sequences, so it does not handle `\` followed by CR/LF as a escaped newline.  This prevents the correct handling of comments where the `//`, `/*` or `*/` sequences are split on 2 lines with one or more escaped newline.
- the program does not handle the sequence `/"` as a `/` followed by the beginning of a string because the `"` is output by `fputc(c, out)` at the end of the body and only the next character is compared to `'` and `"`.  Same problem for `/'`.
- the program suppresses all escaped newlines including those outside comments, which is not what the test files seem to expect.
- it does not handle trigraphs such as `??/` that translate to `\` *before* the escaped newline removal (support for trigraphs would be pedantic as this feature has been removed from the latest C Standard is never used except in test suites).
- it does not handle single quotes used in the C++ style digit separators now standard in C23 (eg: `int x = 1'000;`). This ugly convention makes it more difficult to parse C tokens properly.  It is quite unfortunate that C23 did not standardize `_` as the digit separator as in almost all other modern languages, a convention that would have been compatible with existing preprocessors and parsers as `_` was already accepted in **pp-numbers**. `1'000` will be interpreted as starting a character constant, causing the rest of the program to be misinterpreted and causing the comment stripping to fail.

Here is a modified version of your program with corrections for the line ending issue and the `/"` and `/'` parsing error.  It still suppresses the escaped newlines, ignores trigraphs and misinterprets `'` as digit separators.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int mygetc0(FILE *in) {
    int c = getc(in);
    if (c == '\r') {
        /*  handle legacy line end combinations */
        c = getc(in);
        if (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ungetc(c, in);
        c = '\n';
    }
    return c;
}

int mygetc(FILE *in) {
    for (;;) {
        int c = mygetc0(in);
        if (c == '\\') {
            c = mygetc0(in);
            if (c == '\n')
                continue;
            if (c != EOF)
                ungetc(c, in);
            c = '\\';
        }
        return c;
    }
}

int skip_line_comment(FILE *in) {
    int c;
    while ((c = mygetc(in)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        continue;
    return c;
}

int skip_block_comment(FILE *in) {
    int c;
    for (;;) {
        while ((c = mygetc(in)) != '*') {
            if (c == EOF)
                return c;
        }
        while ((c = mygetc(in)) == '*')
            continue;
        if (c == EOF)
            return c;
        if (c == '/')
            return ' ';
    }
}

void removeComments(FILE *in, FILE *out) {
    int c;
    while ((c = mygetc(in)) != EOF) {
        if (c == '"' || c == '\'') {
            int separator = c;
            fputc(c, out);
            while ((c = mygetc(in)) != separator && c != EOF) {
                fputc(c, out);
                if (c == '\\') {
                    c = mygetc(in);
                    if (c == EOF)
                        break;
                    fputc(c, out);
                }
            }
        } else if (c == '/') {
            c = mygetc(in);
            if (c == '/') {
                c = skip_line_comment(in);
            } else
            if (c == '*') {
                c = skip_block_comment(in);
            } else {
                if (c != EOF)
                    ungetc(c, in);
                c = '/';
            }
        }
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        fputc(c, out);
    }
}

int strip_file(const char *inName) {
    FILE *in;
    FILE *out;
    int len = strlen(inName);

    if (len >= 2 && !strcmp(inName + len - 2, ".c"))
        len -= 2;

    char outName[len + 4];
    snprintf(outName, sizeof outName, "%.*s.wc", len, inName);

    if ((in = fopen(inName, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", inName, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if ((out = fopen(outName, "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", outName, strerror(errno));
        fclose(in);
        return 1;
    }

    removeComments(in, out);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int res = 0;
    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            res |= strip_file(argv[i]);
        }
    } else {
        res |= strip_file("test.c");
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I agree that the test inputs and outputs are eccentric and make testing extremely difficult.  (The file names caused me some grief too, much to my chagrin — some shell scripts of mine that I thought were reasonably bulletproof turned out not to be.)  Expected results 2 and 13 do not contain any EOL sequences at all (2 contains just a slash; 13 contains just abc).  That's not a DOS line ending; it isn't a Unix line ending either.  As you'll see from my later comments to the question, the inputs are not even vaguely valid as C code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree 100% . I too had to rename the files and stopped reading when I discovered inconsistencies in the first test file.

Comment: And I agree that C++14 did no one a service by choosing `'` instead of `_` as a digit separator (though I recognize that they'd tied their hands by accepting `_xyz` as a type-indicating suffix to numeric literals, but that too was probably not a good idea).  C23 follows C++ with the numeric punctuation — and life is a lot harder for ad hoc parsing of C source code!

Comment: You did a good job outlining the problems.  I feel sorry for the class expected to produce a working program.