# integer literal single quote inside ifdef __cplusplus

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a header that is shared between C and C++ with some C++ specific code in it. So i use `#ifdef __cplusplus` inside it.

However, I have a value defined with an integer literal and a single quote as a separator: `int a = 0B0000'0001;`, and it looks like the preprocessor does not like it.

It`s working correctly with visual studio, but not linux, both with gcc and unifdef (that helped me understand the error)

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
    int a = 0B0000'0001;
#endif
```

This simple code will break C code.

The easy solution would be to remove the single quote. But if there is another solution, it would be nice to know

EDIT: the duplicate kinda answer the question, but it's not the same since I dont actually need to use the digit separator in C (but the preprocessor does)

So, to sum up:

- if you have gcc >=12: use flag -std=c2x
- if you dont, you can use a workaround: `// workaround: final quote for pre-c2x: '` on the same line

Comment: @Siguza Not really, the problem is more with `#ifdef` not doing the right thing. The entire line should be removed before compilation when this is compiled in C.

Comment: Isn't the error is in C++? if you use pre-C++14 standard...

Comment: Compile with `gcc -std=c2x` (and the `x` will become `3` or `4` soon).  That sort of punctuation in numbers is part of C23.  It's going to make life hell for ad hoc C parsers.

Comment: @Jarod42 the error is in C, but yes thats what Yksisarvinen said, the content inside the ifdef isnt removed

Comment: See C11 [§6.10.1 Conditional inclusion ¶6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p6): _If it evaluates to false (zero), the group that it controls is skipped: directives are processed only through the name that determines the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the directives' preprocessing tokens are ignored, as are the other preprocessing tokens in the group._. The problem is that it works on "preprocessing tokens", and prior to C23, the `'` starts a character constant token, but there is no matching close quote, so the token is invalid.

Comment: Adding `// workaround: final quote for pre-c2x: '` might be a workaround.

Comment: Punctuating the binary in octal digit groupings would work too: `0B00'000'001`.  Always use an even number of punctuation characters! 0B00100000'00000100'00000000'00000010'00000000'00101010'00000000'00111000` — ouch; 64-bit binary isn't sensible!  And that has 7 punctuators too!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How are answers that don't mention the need to have paired quotes an answer to this question? Your comment(s) make a good answer (and should be posted), the duplicate does not.

Comment: When you ask about an error, it's customary and useful to include the error message in the question.

Comment: You can also put the C++ stuff in a different file and have `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#include "./cpp_header.hpp"` `#endif` so the C preprocessor doesn't even open the file which has `0B0000'0001` in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring commentary into an answer and expanding on the discussion.*</sup>

C++14 was the first standard to include numeric punctuation using `'` to separate groups of digits.  There are technical reasons why C++ could not use `_` instead of `'`.  C++14 also added binary constants, prefixed by `0b` or `0B`.

The numeric punctuation and binary constants features will be added to C23.  This brings it into line with C++, but the numeric punctuation makes ad hoc parsing of C code much harder than it was beforehand.

It means you can compile the code with a version of GCC that recognizes `-std=c2x` (or `-std=c23` or `-std=c24` — I'm not sure which they'll decide on).

You can't compile the code with a C compiler that only recognizes C18 (or is that C17?) or an earlier standard.  That's because the input is tokenized by the C preprocessor.

The C11 standard [§6.10.1 Conditional inclusion ¶6](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p6) specifies:

> Each directive's condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group that it controls is skipped: directives are processed only through the name that determines the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the directives' preprocessing tokens are ignored, as are the other preprocessing tokens in the group. Only the first group whose control condition evaluates to true (nonzero) is processed. If none of the conditions evaluates to true, and there is a `#else` directive, the group controlled by the `#else` is processed; lacking a `#else` directive, all the groups until the `#endif` are skipped.

The problem is that it works on "preprocessing tokens", and prior to C23, the `'` in `0B0000'0001` starts a character constant token, but there is no matching close quote, so the token is invalid/incomplete.

There are a few possible but nasty, hacky workarounds.  One, suggested by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704798/integer-literal-single-quote-inside-ifdef-cplusplus?noredirect=1#comment136991394_77704798), is:

> Adding `// workaround: final quote for pre-c2x: '` might be a workaround.

In a similar vein, you could ensure that all punctuated numbers contain an even number of single quotes.  For example, punctuating the binary in octal digit groupings would work too: `0B00'000'001`. Always use an even number of punctuation characters!

And [Arteyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704798/integer-literal-single-quote-inside-ifdef-cplusplus?noredirect=1#comment136992637_77704798):

> You can also put the C++ stuff in a different file and have
>
> ```
> #ifdef __cplusplus
> #include "./cpp_header.hpp"
> #endif
> ```
>
> so the C preprocessor doesn't even open the file which has `0B0000'0001` in it.

Note that it isn't very sensible to represent 64-bit numbers in binary, even with punctuation. And if you punctuate in octets, that will have 7 punctuators too!

```
0B10100000'00000100'00000000'00000010'00000000'00101010'00000000'00111000
```

It would be more sensible in hex, but there would be three separators between four quartets of hex digits, still causing trouble with compilers for C18 or earlier and C++11 or earlier:

```
0xA004'0002'002A'0038
```

My recommendation would be:

- Don't use numeric punctuation until all the C and C++ compilers you need to work with support it.
- Don't use binary to represent 64-bit values.  Use hex instead.

(I'll note in passing that C++ raw string literals are even more of a nightmare for ad hoc code parsers.  Mercifully, raw string literals are not a part of C23.)

Comment: What do you mean by ad hoc code parsers?

Comment: @PasserBy: an ad hoc parser doesn't understand all the details of C code because it doesn't need to.  The C90 to C18 syntax is fairly easy to parse, especially if you don't try to deal with backslash-newline combinations.  You can use such parsers for all sorts of useful work.  However, with the addition of punctuated numbers, it is easier for ad hoc parsers to run into problems.  As a f'rinstance: both `#include <double"quote.h>` and `#include <single'quote.h>` are legitimate header names (no strings) — but many ad hoc parsers aren't aware of the special rules that apply to the header name.

Comment: See also the comments to [Delete comments from a C file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77670749/15168).